# Discord.js v14 Missing permissions when given

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So today I've tried to create command in discord bot that can rename user which typed the command to something else. However no matter what I do this code allways returns error Missing Permissions.

```
const {Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder, Guild} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client(
    {
        intents:
        [
            GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
            GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
            GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        ]
    }
);

client.on("ready", () =>
{
    console.log("Bot is ready!");

    const nicknameCH = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('changenick')
    .setDescription('Changing nickname')
    .addStringOption((option) =>
        {
            return option
            .setName("newnick")
            .setRequired(true)
        })

    client.application.commands.create(nicknameCH);

});

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => 
{
    if(!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    if(interaction.commandName === 'changenick')
    {
        const stringOption = interaction.options.getString("newnick").toString();

        const thisUser = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.user.id);
        thisUser.setNickname(stringOption);

        interaction.reply('Changing to: ' + stringOption);
    }
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsCWw.png)

I've set bot role to highest place in roles tab on discord server settings and given him Admin permission, reinvited him.

I'm expecting to change user nickname no matter if he has permissions to do that or not via bot

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to change nickname of owner of the server (i guess you). None has permission to change nick of owner. (No matter how high is the bot). Use that command on some of your friend or your alt account.